# Passing array from PHP to JavaScript using json_encode shows empty values

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm using the following code to send an array from PHP to JavaScript, but it doesn't seem to work using `json_encode()`. Here's my code:

In PHP:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row; 
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
var test = "<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>";
alert (test);
```

Result of var_dump():

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'proj_nbr' => string '0111' (length=4)
      'proj_name' => string 'General' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      'proj_nbr' => string '' (length=0)
      'proj_name' => string 'New Project' (length=11)
```

It displays just blank values. My PHP version is 5.3.6.

Comment: "Blank values" as in an empty alert box, or empty cell values?

Comment: After filling `$arr`, do a `var_dump($arr)` and take a look at the source of the page. What does it come up as?

Comment: it shows data in array form. updating question with the result

Comment: If you look at the page source, is the json there?  That will narrow down where your issue is.

Comment: I just added json2.js to my js library and included in my php. So when I view source, that's the only instance of json i can see.. But no change in the output.. this may sound stupid to you folks, but this is my first experience with json.. Thanks!!

Comment: In the page source as viewed *in your browser*, what appears instead of the php in the line `var test = "<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>";`?

Comment: In page source, I see `var = "[]";` Now I see the problem. But what is missing in my code??

Comment: @user1165952: Are you sure you don't change `$arr` anywhere else? May we see the full source of your file, please?

Comment: @minitech $arr is an arbitrary array i have created to test json encode functionality and its the last line in my php section and the js code given above is the first line of code in js section. So I'm sure $arr is not changed anywhere.

Comment: Are the "PHP section" and "JS section" in the same file?

Comment: @jedwards yes, they are in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.. My mistake here was the double quotes in javascript                   `var test = "<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>";`

should be
    `var test = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;`

also changed `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `mysql_fetch_row`.

But the data is not in array format. I got data in this format `(0111,General,)`. I need data in array format. Any suggestions?